# How to get the last two digits of a number in an efficient way?

Tags: c

I have number, say 1234 ,and I want to get the last two digits from the number i.e. 34.

Currently I am doing it using `%100` and `%10` operations.
Is there any other efficient way to do it?

Comment: Depending on the architecture, the answer may be yes. However, I'd much rather read `% 10` than the crazy bitshifting operators required. See [Hacker's Delight](http://www.hackersdelight.org/divcMore.pdf).

Comment: When you're fiddling with digits you will have other runtime penalties elsewhere. Trust the optimization of your compiler and use `%10` unless you have an evidence that it hurts.

Comment: Please post a runnable specimen. If you have a performance problem I wouldn't start with % on primitive types as my suspect.

Answer (score 1):

if it's a string you want the last two characters,

Else if it;s an integer doing %100 first storing the result in an `int` and then doing %10 on that is about as efficient as it gets. (`short` might work better than `int` here, might not)

integers are stored as binary numbers and the CPU can't see the 'last base 10 digit' 
just by looking at the number, it has to do the remainder computation to get that.

Comment: Why might `short` work better? In all likelihood, it won't. On x86, it'll generate code, that's executing slower than going with an `int`. In general, unless there is a **very** good reason not to use `int`, don't.

Comment: Division is hard, narrow divides are faster - 80386 seems to need 11+width clocks https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2006/readings/i386/IDIV.htm

Comment: So it is potentially faster, when writing 16-bit code. However, in 32-bit code, this requires use of the `66h` operand-size prefix, which causes a major performance hit. Again, unless there is a compelling reason not to use `int`, go ahead and use it.

Comment: like I said maybe faster maybe not

Comment: Recommendations always come with a rationale, so that you know when good advice turns bad. As put, that comment is largely devoid of any useful information. This answer's quality likely goes up with that statement removed (or at least augmented).

Comment: Hey everyone, just a heads up, but %100 doesn't work on an int such as 2460001. The result isn't going to return "01", it's going to lose the zero and return 1. In my case, I actually need the zero, even though 01 isn't technically an int. I was just trying to avoid converting the int to a string just to get "01", and was looking for a faster way to get the last two digits. Unfortunately, %100 doesn't guarantee that you'll actually get TWO digits.

Comment: digits aren't a property of ints, thery're a property of strings  how many zeros you see depenmds on how you choose to convert it to a string.